# Google Chrome Downloads FTP Directory Instead of In-Browser Display

Tags: google-chrome, ftp

I am trying to view an FTP web directory in Google Chrome. Instead of simply loading the page in-browser, it downloads a file to my computer called `download`, which contains a directory listing of the FTP web directory.

Why is Chrome doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that Chrome is still parsing the page as http://website.com/ftp. You should try using ftp://website.com/ftp instead.

Comment: I am using ftp://

Comment: Could be a problem on your site's configuration, disallowing directory listing. I just tested on both Firefox and Chromium and works fine from here.

Comment: Can you let me test the site you're trying to go to?

Comment: Unfortunately, the site is password-protected and I can't give out the login information. I am going to try and contact the web hosting company and try to work with them

Comment: Sure no problem